# Where to place if statement in a loop when checking values of a dictionary

Tags: python

```
person_language = {
    'john' : ['python' , 'c'],
    'sarah' : ['python' , 'html'],
    'jason' : ['java'],
    'michael' : ['javascript'],
    }


for person,languages in person_language.items():

    print(f"{person}'s favourite language are:")


    for language in languages:
            print(language)
```

**Noob Alert**

I can't figure out where to use if statement to print 'is' when there is only one value for a key (e.g. java), and 'are' when there are multiple values for a key (e.g. python, html).

The output I want is:

```
    john's favourite language are:
    python
    c
    sarah's favourite language are:
    python
    html
    jason's favourite language is:
    java
    michael's favourite language is:
    javascript
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for person,languages in person_language.items():
    print("{}'s favourite language {}:".format(person, "is" if len(languages) == 1 else "are"))
    for language in languages:
            print(language)
```

or

```
for person,languages in person_language.items():
    print("{person}'s favourite language {'is' if len(languages) == 1 else 'are'}:")
    for language in languages:
            print(language)
```

The format method can be useful in this case because you can add an if statement in it if the length of languages is equal to 1.
But you can use it the same in f string with changing the " to ' inside the curly brackets.

Answer (score 2):

```
for person,languages in person_language.items():
    verb = 'is' if len(languages) == 1 else "are"
    print(f"{person}'s favourite language {verb}:")
```